# Spark - scala: shuffle RDD / split RDD into two random parts randomly

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

How can I take a rdd array of spark, and split it into two rdds randomly so each rdd will include some part of data (lets say 97% and 3%).

I thought to shuffle the list and then `shuffledList.take((0.97*rddList.count).toInt)`

But how can I Shuffle the rdd?

Or is there a better way to split the list?

Comment: Are all the items unique (i.e. no duplicates?) Just wondering if you can use `takeSample()` and then filter the sample out of the original list.

Comment: Can be duplicate, but why does it matter, what would you be able to do if they are unique?

Comment: OK, I don't think the takeSample approach would work with duplicates.

Comment: It is also problematic because I want to save also the second part (i.e. the 3%)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've found a simple and fast way to split the array:

```
val Array(f1,f2) = data.randomSplit(Array(0.97, 0.03))
```

It will split the data using the provided weights.

Comment: how to change the type of ```f1 f2``` to ```DataFrame``` ?

Answer (score 6):

You should use `randomSplit` method:

```
def randomSplit(weights: Array[Double], seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[RDD[T]]

// Randomly splits this RDD with the provided weights.
// weights for splits, will be normalized if they don't sum to 1
// returns split RDDs in an array
```

Here is its [implementation](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/1efb3698b6cf39a80683b37124d2736ebf3c9d9a/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.scala#L373) in spark 1.0:

```
def randomSplit(weights: Array[Double], seed: Long = Utils.random.nextLong): Array[RDD[T]] = {
    val sum = weights.sum
    val normalizedCumWeights = weights.map(_ / sum).scanLeft(0.0d)(_ + _)
    normalizedCumWeights.sliding(2).map { x =>
       new PartitionwiseSampledRDD[T, T](this, new BernoulliSampler[T](x(0), x(1)),seed)
    }.toArray
}
```

Comment: @Boern You can hopefully see that the other answer was edited later. If this answer is outdated, feel free to edit it.